# Heroku is returning error H13 with a simple Flask application

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple Flask application to Heroku. The app starts there and binds to 0.0.0.0:[port] but when requesting a GET on my URL at heroku, I can see the request in the log file but it results with an error in Heroku:

```
at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=[appname].herokuapp.com request_id=02c415da-a59f-42e2-84ab-37ab8b11373d fwd="[IP address]" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

This is the Flask code:

```
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>Index</h1>"


@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return "<h1>success</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = os.environ.get('PORT')
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```

Procfile:

```
web: python test.py
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm unable to reproduce the error using the same code and procfile. Can you reveal more context/configuration details that might be relevant? Using this code without openssl installed results in a crash due to `ssl_context`, but that's unrelated to the h13 error.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the port to `int` and you can remove `ssl_context` as Heroku supports that out-of-the-box (`https://appname.herokuapp.com`)

```
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)) 
app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not help.
For some reason Heroku still throws this error:
2021-04-13T18:51:23.814559+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on https://0.0.0.0:54311/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
        2021-04-13T18:51:31.412365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=[appname].herokuapp.com request_id=e954e1d4-8c79-4431-856a-302ad82062c7 fwd="[IP]" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Comment: Looks like it starts up correctly but there is no response from the endpoint. I would try to log something (to check it is actually invoked) and also try the other endpoint (`/test`)